# Help with install. Cannot get irq-1 for the hot plug error

Tags: boot

I'm trying to install Ubuntu coming from Pop os and when I try to boot up from the flash drive I get Pciehp: cannot get irq-1 for the hotplug error.

Specs 136000k i-5,
Aorus z790 elite mobo,
Aorus rtx 3070 ti

I found people who were getting the error after installing Ubuntu but I can't even get it to boot from the flash drive to install.

Edit: Running in safe mode from the USB seems to have done the trick for me. I was able to get it to start and install.